# Python - How Ignore Script Name When Zero Filenames Given.

Tags: argv

I'm writing a program that will accept zero or unlimited number of files that the program will read through and display an output result. Right now the program will accept as many files (argv) in the command line. But what I want it to do is, if no file names are given, then print the program but display no value.

The name of program below is: **file.py**

When I run this file in the command line (*e.g python file.py*) The program is reading the script (file.py) and giving the output result. Is there a way for the program to display the string below but provide no output result?

```
    from sys import argv

    script , filenames = argv[0], argv[0:]


for file in filenames: 
    print ('-' * 40) 
    with open(file) as f: 

        var1 = f.read() 
        var1_b = var1.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)                
        var1_c = ''.join(i for i in var1_b if not i.isdigit())                      

        print "YOUR FILE NAME IS: '[%r]'" % (file)

        var2 = var1_c.split() 
        var3 = len(var2) 

        print 'THE TOTAL NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE FILE IS "[%d]"' % var3 

        var4 = var1_c.split()[0]
        var5 = len(var4) 

        print 'THE FIRST WORD IS "[%s]" AND ITS THE LENGTH OF "[%d]" CHARACTERS'  % (var4 , var5)

        var6 = max(var1_c.split(), key = len)                            
        var7 = len(var6)
```

Current Output:

```
YOUR FILE NAME IS: '['file.py']'
THE TOTAL NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE FILE IS "[233]"
THE FIRST WORD IS "[THE]" AND ITS THE LENGTH OF "[3]" CHARACTERS
```

Desired Output:

```
 YOUR FILE NAME IS: '['  ']'
THE TOTAL NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE FILE IS "[   ]"
THE FIRST WORD IS "[THE]" AND ITS THE LENGTH OF "[   ]" CHARACTERS
```